# How to call a method that affects multiple components when Material Sidenav is toggled?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Material Sidenav-component inside my app.component.

The problem is that when the menu is toggled, it affects the size of the parent-component on multiple charts that I have in the application. The charts therefore needs to be re-rendered each time the sidenav is toggled to fit the size of their parent-components.

To re-render the charts throughout my application I need to call the render()-method on a html-element that I can get via @ViewChild() on each chart-components typescript file.

I don't know if it's possible to get an instance of the chart-components or their parent "dashboard-component" via app.component.ts because these components are nested multiple steps down the "file-tree". Perhaps I can use a service?

I would be very glad if anyone could guide me in the right direction regarding how to accomplish this.

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: Use an event service as described here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the responsive charts (responsive CSS)  to avoid re-rendering. if no data is changing in charts then re-rendering them is not a good idea.

However if you still want to re-render them on toggle of sidenav, you can use rxjs **BehaviorSubject** and broadcast the value on toggle of sidenav. your Charts will be subscribing to that broadcasted event and re-render on toggle.
For Example inside UtilityService:

```
let bSubject = new BehaviorSubject("hideSidebar");
```

In AppComponent:

```
toggleSidenav(){
    this.utilityService.bSubject.next("showsidebar");
}
```

In your chart component:

```
onInit(){
    this.utilityService.bSubject.subscribe(value => {
      console.log("Subscription recieved--update charts", value); 
    });
}
```